# Is it possible to use ARM-M4 Cortex Microcontroller to process a simple image?

Tags: image-processing, arm, cortex-m

My school project is to measure the distances and angles between the center and several mark points (basically a panel with a big red spot). My idea is using one camera and process the red spot on each panel, the red color can be distinguished from surronding colors. I have googled some materials and i know that it can be implemented with Python and OpenCV library and a OS-based computer. But i think my image processing is quite simple ( just read the color and pixel of the spot) so i dont need those OS-based computer. Is it possible, i still have zero knowledge about image processing. Thanks! I appreciate it a lot

Comment: Yes, this should be possible.

Comment: yes this is possible but you need some RAM memory for that ...

Comment: @Spektre Most (all?) implementations of Cortex M4 will have some embedded RAM, some of the parts quite a lot, stm32f469 for example has 384KB!

Comment: The cpu should be capable enough but as someone pointed out the  ram size might be a little bit low. Is CM4 required by the course ? Otherwise a Raspberry Pi will give you more bang for the buck, unless you plan to build the hardware yourself and not use a ready made development board.

Comment: There are plenty of dev boards available which have a significant (in embedded terms) amount of external RAM if you need more than available in the chip itself. Some dev boards / processors also have camera interfaces built in.

Comment: @Colin__s 384KB is usually not enough for image processing depends on what exactly will be implemented but even a single frame in memory from the camera can be bigger (`640x480x24bit = 900KByte` !!!) yes you can do some things on scan lines only but some CV and DIP algorithms require whole image and some even one or more shadow/back buffers and suddenly 384KB is not enough anymore ... not to mention you need to have memory for the program and its engine too (that is not counting OS if present)

Comment: @Spektre thanks for pointing that out but i think it is still nearly impossible since it has to take the picture -> transfering data to MCU -> processing the image and find the spot (which is still a mistery algorithm that i couldn't find anywhere) -> rotate the motor few degree and then take another picture -> so on. I'm afraid 80Mhz or even 120MHz clock MCU can't do that task within a second ( time is one of constrains). SO, i've decided to use my laptop with Python and OpenCV to handle the image processing, the MCU will take the rotate control. There's still lots stuff to learn....

Comment: @VietNguyen well I would not try Python on MCU for this but in C/C++ it should be doable. You just have to shrink the input data not process al pixels etc ... for example during image acquisition you can directly test if scan line holds wanted object (color present) if not throw it away. this way you can store just bbox of desired area. you can also use 8/16 bit grayscale instead RGB to ease up things (based on distance to tgeting color), centered FIR noise removal on scan line etc. All of this is doable on scan lines. And the rest is questionable as we did not see the image.

Comment: @VietNguyen adding SRAM to MCU is normal if you are using some kind of KIT some of them usually have SRAM chip 0.5 - 8 MByte. do not use Flash slot for this as that would need to owerwrite a lot degrading the life time of it. The speed should not be a big problem you would not believe what I did on 20MHz 4 MC MCUs and now I am on 66MHz 1 MC MCUs with DMA/PLL/interaces present ... exploiting internal architecture can give you huge boost. Anyway I would start to code this on PC and optimize to target MCU until fit in ...